# Copy files recursively

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def ignore_list(path, files):
    filesToIgnore = []
    for fileName in files:
        fullFileName = os.path.join(os.path.normpath(path), fileName)
        if not os.path.isdir(fullFileName) and not fileName.endswith('pyc') and not fileName.endswith('ui') and not fileName.endswith('txt') and not fileName == '__main__.py' and not fileName == 'myfile.bat':
            filesToIgnore.append(fileName)

    return filesToIgnore

# Start of script    
shutil.copytree(srcDir, dstDir, ignore=ignore_list)
```

I want to change the `if` line containing files to copy.  Here I have to give the filenames separately, but I want to change it like it should take filenames from a list containing all file names.

How can I do this?

Comment: How's the list of filenames looks like? If it is a list of files to ignore, why don't you just pass it in `ignore=`?

Comment: If i get this correctly your method ignore_list should run through the path directory and look for files matching your if and return a list of files that should not be copied?

Comment: the files which i want to copy are in the "if" line, i just want chage this line, so that i should check "if" condition with a list(containing *.pyc,*.txt, *.ui, __main__.py, myfile.txt)

Answer (score 1):

What I could understand from your question is, you could simply write:

```
if fileName not in fileNameList:
    filesToIgnore.append(fileName)
```

where `fileNameList` is a list of file names which you want to copy.

**Update:**

```
fName, fileExtension = os.path.splitext(fileName)
if fileName not in fileNameList or fileExtension not in allowedExtensionList:
    filesToIgnore.append(fileName)
```

Comment: can u give me a replacement of "if" line in my code with your method, because it contains *.pyc, *.ui, *.txt and __main__.py, myfile.txt

Comment: If you are providing full name of the files (with extensions) in your list, you do not need to put the check for file extensions. Just put the files which are allowed/acceptable.

Comment: there are so many .pyc, .ui and .txt files so i cant give the full name of all files

Comment: Updated my code, now you can create a list of allowed extensions and a list of allowed file names.

Comment: I tried your method(update:), but generated directory is empty, why that happened ?

Answer (score 0):

You could also write a method like the following.

```
def ignore_files(path, extensions, wantedfiles):
      ignores = []

      for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(path):
          for filename in filenames:
            if any(filename.endswith(_) for _ in extensions):
                  ignores.append(os.path.join(os.path.normpath(path), filename))
            elif filename in wantedfiles:
                  ignores.append(os.path.join(os.path.normpath(path), filename))

      return ignores

# Start of script
ignore_list = ignore_files(srcDir, ['pyc', 'uid', 'txt'])
shutil.copytree(srcDir, dstDir, ignore=ignore_list)
```

Comment: how to include the condition to copy files particular files in your answer code

Comment: I've updated the code, this should even include specific files like in your example "main.py", you just need to pass those in a separate list

Comment: shutil.copytree(srcDir, dstDir, ignore=ignore_list) -this line has given me error  TypeError: 'list' object is not callable